# The getIndexOfChild() of the JTree's TreeModel not being called

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtree

I have created a custom `TreeModel` for the `JTree` component. I have found
that its `getIndexOfChild()` method is never called. The only information
that I found regarding this method is an obscure message: *This is not called in the JTree's default mode: use a naive implementation*, which gets repeated over and over in multiple examples creating a custom tree model—for instance [here](http://www.java-forum.org/awt-swing-javafx-swt/98848-kommentare-xml-jtree-anzeigen.html) or [here](http://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/source/browse/trunk/src/com/sittinglittleduck/DirBuster/gui/JTableTree/AbstractTreeTableModel.java?r=1071).
Even in the [Genealogy example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#GenealogyExample) of the official Swing tutorial the method is implemented but never called. There is no explanation in the documentation.

Why is this method never called? And if the above message is correct, what is the
*default mode* of a `JTree`? Is there a mode in which the method is called?

**Later edit**
It seems that the `getChild()` and the `getIndexOfChild()` methods are somehow
linked together. If the `getChild()` method returns a `File` object or a `String`
object, the `getIndexOfChild()` is not called, for some reason. It gets called if
it returns a custom object, or even if it returns a `new Object()`.

Here is a small example where the issue is reproduced:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

class MyModel implements TreeModel {

    private final String root;
    private final ArrayList lst;
    private final HashMap map;

    public MyModel(String root) {

        this.root = root;
        lst = new ArrayList();
        lst.add("Lenovo");
        lst.add("Coca cola");
        lst.add("Mercedes");
        lst.add("Wilson");

        map = new HashMap();
        map.put(root, lst);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
        return !node.equals("Brands");
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildCount(Object parent) {

        ArrayList list = (ArrayList) map.get((String) parent);
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(Object parent, int idx) {

        ArrayList list = (ArrayList) map.get((String) parent);
        return list.get(idx);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
        System.out.println("getIndexOfChild");

        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) {
    }

    @Override
    public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
    }
}

public class TreeModelEx extends JFrame {

    public TreeModelEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        createTree();

        setTitle("TreeModel");
        setSize(400, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void createTree() {

        String root = "Brands";

        MyModel model = new MyModel(root);
        JTree tree = new JTree(model);

        add(new JScrollPane(tree));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TreeModelEx ex = new TreeModelEx();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If we launch the example, the message `System.out.println("getIndexOfChild");`
is not printed to the console.

Comment: hashmap hasn't internal indexing, same issue in JTable (e.g get row, column for Renderer e.i.)

Comment: Yes, it would cause probably a problem, since to my knowledge, the purpose of the `getIndexOfChild()` method is to do some ordering of the nodes. Nevertheless, it should be called. In the meantime, I have found the this method is somehow linked with the `getChild()` method. It is not called if the `getChild()` method returns a `File` object or a `String` object. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not telling it to print you are simply printing a text..

Try this  `System.out.println(getIndexOfChild);`

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(getIndexOfChild(parent, child));
```